# codeigniter csrf error on form submission

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, csrf, csrf-protection

I have a form using codeigniter brackets

```
echo form_open('signup');

echo form_close();
```

and when i submit it i get the following error

```
An Error Was Encountered

The action you have requested is not allowed.
```

**NOT** `always` but often...

even when the hidden inputfield exist inside the form:

```
<div style="display:none">
<input type="hidden" value="token name is here" name="csrf_token_name">
</div>
```

this also happens on a similar form(signin)

**EDIT: html generated via form**

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="http://www.example.com/signup">
<div style="display:none">
<input type="hidden" value="93565fb5855d31af3d46bd655b11a4a6" name="csrf_token_name">
</div>
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" maxlength="20" value="" name="username">
<input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" value="" name="email">
<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" value="" name="password">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Sign up" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Please, post the HTML code generated for your form. Thanks.

Comment: That particular error is thrown by the function csrf_show_error() in system/code/Security.php when the CSRF token in $_COOKIE doesn't match your $_POST['csrf_token_name'].

There's a lot of things that can be causing problems here:
a) Are you making an AJAX request that can be changing your $_COOKIE token before you send the form?
b) Are you making cross-domain requests? Or maybe changing protocols?

If you post a link with you app, maybe I can see what's going on.

Comment: when i do ajax requests i dont get the above error... this happens on this form where from http://www.domain.com/ (where the form is) it takes me to http://www.domain.com/signup to complete the registration... and it happens really rare... i am not doing cross-domain requests simply fron index page to /signup

Comment: And you $config['base_url'] has www or not?

Comment: yes it has www... actually its http://www.domain.com/ and i also force via htaccess the www part if missing...

Comment: You should put your www.domain.com as your base_url. Otherwise you're forcing a redirect on each request with your .htaccess. Another thing worth checking out is your csrf_expire in your config.php. Also, are you doing any Ajax request before submitting (ie. checking user availability)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are doing it wrong.

try this

```
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>" />
```

the value must be what codeigniter calculates for the csrf token.

or use form helper and codeigniter will add this hidden field automatically.

Comment: the hidden field is added automatically since i use form_open()... i didnt add it manually if thats you thought..

Comment: can you post the code for the form? a bit strange if you are already using the form helper.

Comment: are you using htaccess to remove index.php in the url?

Comment: i use the default codeigniter htaccess just edited it a bit to always add www if it does not exist in the url...i have only set $config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: try http://www.site.com/index.php/controller/method          If it succeeds, it means your htaccess isn't overriding. and i didn't see method name in your form action. Does the Post variables goes to index function in signup controller?

Comment: there is a method in the <form> tags... yes it goes into the index function in signup controller

Comment: oopsy. I was talking about method as in 'signup/method' in form action. but try adding index.php/controller/method. Your form seems errorless otherwise.

Comment: it works most of the times... just sometimes it throws the above error... i really dont want to add index.php in the URL...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just increased 'csrf_expire' variable - the number in seconds the token should expire.

> From $config['csrf_expire'] = 7200; 
>   To
>   $config['csrf_expire'] = 28800;

Answer (score -3):

change $config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;

to

$config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE; in config file

Comment: can you explain that ?

Comment: It will make the system vulnerable.

Answer (score -4):

If you just want to get rid of the errors altogether...
The **easiest solution** to get around them would be to:

1. Open your */config/**config.php*** file
2. Find the line below:
   `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;`
3. Replace it with...
   `$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;`
4. Save changes.

---

**CAUTION:** Turning off the CSRF protection means you are left open to CSRF attacks.

Comment: why would exposure to CSRF attack be recommended ?