# Call a class method from Javascript form

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, methods, bonfire

In order to create dynamically a form, Im doing something like (inside a js function) :

```
member = memberInfo.values[0];

// create the sign up form
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('name',"linkedInForm");
f.setAttribute('action', "users/register");

// add fields to the form
var fName = document.createElement("input");
fName.setAttribute('type',"hidden");
f.setAttribute('name',"linkedInForm");
fName.setAttribute('value',member.firstName);
```

I'm adding the fields to the form

```
// append fields to the form
f.appendChild(fName);
```

And then submitting it:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);

f.submit();
```

This js form is meant to be treated by a method called: 'register' in the class 'users' ( `f.setAttribute('action', "users/register");`)

But All I'm getting is an error 500 Internal server error. and in CodeIgniter logs :

```
An Error Was Encountered. The action you have requested is not allowed.
```

Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274880/codeigniter-csrf-error-on-form-submittion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error seems to be generated by Security.php , change the `csrf_protection` to `false` at config.php on config folder.

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

you better to see the bellow link for more reference

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/163976/